# Missing GA4 event parameters

Tags: events, analytics

I have recently started to use Google Analytics 4 for event tracking, using Google Tag Manager to send events to Analytics. I have set up the custom variables in Tag Manager as well as in GA4.

Everything seems to work very well in Tag Manager's debug mode, and also if I look up the events in real-time view I get the requested event along with all the parameters I have set in Tag Manager. However, once I look up the events for the last couple of days in the Engagement -> Event view, a couple of my parameters are missing, and also I'm not getting the same hit count for each parameter, even though each event has all parameters set:

[image: Missing Event Parameters]

As you can see, 86 events have been recorded, but the event count for the parameters widely varies.

Here's a screenshot of my Tag manager settings:
[image: Current Tag Manager Settings]

I have tried to set up a new event with the same parameters, but (logically) I got the same result. I am under the strong impression I'm missing something obvious here. Does anyone have experience with this, or has anyone come across this same issue?

Comment: Hi @GerrirElbrink, it is a bit of a late one but all your event parameters (a.k.a custom dimensions, a.k.a custom definitions) need to created in the Custom Definitions section of the UI first.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply. You mean before actually sending events?

Comment: for the Event Name you cannot write {{Event}}. you should write a name for your event, and you should create custom dimensions/metrics and somehow wait for 48 hours.

Comment: Hey @GerritElbrink - did you ever solve this? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: No, I created new events with the same parameters, and now it works...

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, you can just try to click on mark as conversion in the Events tab, and this should save them. I think for some reason GA4 doesn't save parameters otherwise...

Answer (score -1):

i cant get this til work with fields and parameters for an event so i try to create a user custom dimension instead and also to send it as a content group and as user property
also i can see the user id under app instance for the standard report user explorer
but i can't filter on or select this one myself

i cant create the custom parameter reports like gerrit did
but yeah create them as custom dimensions /metric first should be the way

ga4 has a bug when you edit a standard report, you add 3 card and deselect one it still thinks you are maxed out and you have to start over...

the test internal users filters dont work, though you can see data in debug and under events, but since i know they work i know try to just make the filters active