# When exploring a user, how can I view the url of the page they viewed?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

In user explorer, I see default page_view events but they don't show page paths when I click into them. New to GA4 and could use any advice. I was expecting the default parameters (page_location, page_referrer) to show up but I only see custom parameters.

[image]

One thought I had was to add a custom page_path to the gtag config but since I am running a SPA, this wasn't working as expected. I was thinking of setting up a custom page view event in the front end code and not use the default page_view.

Comment: Relevant question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68619329/missing-ga4-event-parameters