# When exploring a user in GA4 User Explorer, how can I view the parameters passes through that event?

Tags: google-analytics-4, universal-analytics

In user explorer in GA4, I see default page_view, scroll, session_start events but they don't show the details like page_path etc. when I click into them. I am new to GA4 and tried searching online to understand how to do it. In User Explorer in UA, I was able to see the Page opened, the Link clicked etc (when I passed event for that). I don't see any parameters
Also, I don't see Click events in this list
I have already gone through the following threads and couldn't still solve the problem:

[When exploring a user, how can I view the url of the page they viewed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74159245/when-exploring-a-user-how-can-i-view-the-url-of-the-page-they-viewed)

[Missing GA4 event parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68619329/missing-ga4-event-parameters)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoMPp.png)

Can someone advise what am I doing wrong or what should I do to get the Parameter values in the events like page_view.
Also, I don't see click events even when the Enhanced Measurements is enabled

Answer (score 0):

Its probably about how you have the account setup.

To automatically track typical clicks in GA4, you need to enable enhanced measurement of events for your property. I found this site useful.

https://www.datadrivenu.com/how-to-track-clicks-in-google-analytics-4/

Comment: I have already enabled enhanced measurement of the events. And that is how it is tracking the events. However, it is not showing any details of the event once I click on it. Also, it is not showing the User Properties which I have set

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar issue.

Sometimes I forget to remove filters.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34251573)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with SPA. I added these parameters (page_url, page_path, and link_text) in my main tag configuration which is triggered by page_view (tag type is GA4 Configuration, area 'Fields to set'). So far it worked for me.
Note that link_text can be tricky, in my case I don't get them always due to inaccurate front-end decisions.