# GA4 User Activity Doesn't Show Event Parameters

Tags: parameters, google-analytics, user-activity, google-analytics-4

Problem (Summary):
In User's Activity, I am able to see my event but when I open it's details, the event parameters values are shown as (not set).

Journey so far:
I posted a question:
[When exploring a user in GA4 User Explorer, how can I view the parameters passes through that event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75636938/when-exploring-a-user-in-ga4-user-explorer-how-can-i-view-the-parameters-passes)
and have since moved further, only in diagnosis, and not in solution. Thus, posting again with more data and full context in hope of getting a solution.

I am integrating GA4 on my website. The integration is through Google Tag Manager. I created an event Tag with event name page_view_manual (because the inbuilt page_view is also giving same issues, so just wanted to be sure). In this, I passed Event Parameters page_path & page_referrer, settings their respective values in Tag. I also added both page_path & page_referrer in custom definitions as Dimensions with Event Scope. [image: Tag With Event Parameters]

I then checked in Tag Assistant that the tag is firing. I also checked in GA4 Debug View [image: Debug View receiving the Parameter Values] that the page_path & page_referrer values are being received by GA4 alongwith the event name page_view_manual.

Problem:
When I go to any particular User's Activity, it shows me a list of events for that user. I am able to see page_view_manual there. But when I open it's details, the event parameters values are shown as (not set).
[image: User Activity Page]

Hoping that someone would have faced a similar problem and found out what the issue is. I already tried looking online but couldn't find much content around Event Parameter values in User Activity Tabs